# Derivation of bias variance trade-off with or without conditional expectation?

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-expectation, bias-variance-tradeoff

I found this nice lecture [here](https://youtu.be/zUJbRO0Wavo?feature=shared) where the bias variance trade-off is explained using conditional expectation - using e.g. $E_{y|X}[...]$

[image]

In this lecture [here](https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/mlsc/Notes/Lecture4/BiasVariance.pdf) I found another proof of the formula without conditional expectation. I show a snapshot again, e.g.

[image]

Now I wonder what the difference between the two is. To me it seems they use slightly different definitions for the different terms, but I am not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your green first picture says $E_{\mathbf{x},y}$ rather than $E_{y \mid \mathbf{x}}$ and I think your second picture does something equivalent.

Comment: @Henry in the fourth line of the first picture he starts to argue using conditional expectation.

Comment: OK, your second case seems to treat $\mathbf{x}$ and $f_i$ as deterministic while your first treats them or their equivalent as random variables